# What is a good X application I can use to test the X server on Solaris?

Tags: x11, solaris

I am using Solaris, and I want to test if the I can use the X server after setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

On Linux, I usually use `xeyes`, `xclock` or `xterm`. But none of these seem to available on Solaris.

Note that I am using the GA release of Oracle Solaris 11.

Comment: Is there some particular attribute that makes it "good" for testing? I would say "any X application you have installed" -- presumably you have one, or you wouldn't be bothering with X in the first place

Comment: All of those are available on Solaris 11 if you install the packages - use `pkg search xeyes` for instance to find the right package.   Whether they're installed by default or not depends on whether you used the text or gui installer.

Comment: @alanc Interesting; both xterm and xeyes are included in the `compatibility/packages/SUNWxwplt` package, whose name leads me to believe it will be dropped by Oracle in the future.

Comment: @NullUserException: you should have found xeyes is in `pkg:/x11/demo` and xterm is in `pkg:/terminal/xterm`.  The `compatibility/packages/SUNWxwplt` depends on those as it installs everything that was in the Solaris 10 SUNWxwplt package, for compatibility with old SVR4 packages that depend on SUNWxwplt and while it may go away, the actual packages should not.

Comment: @alanc Would you have any clues on this one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/ ?

Comment: @NullUserException - sorry, no, I've not tried installing the Oracle DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am sorry, I failed to mention that I was using Oracle Solaris 11.

In this release, none of these come installed by default (used the text installer). You have to install them using the package manager. To find which package contains the application you want use `pkg search`:

```
pkg search xeyes
```

I used the `compatibility/packages/SUNWxwplt` package and it installed `xterm` and `xeyes` to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I alway used xeyes when I was still a Solaris-admin. I am quite sure that it was a standard with Versions 2.5, 2.6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 13):

```
xset -q > /dev/null
```

I found this over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637005/x-server-running (in response to a somewhat misleadingly worded question).

- quick
- usable in scripts
- quiet if OK; diagnostic for problem on stderr

Answer (score 2):

You may want to expand your environment variable `PATH` to directory `/usr/openwin/bin`:

```
 PATH=$PATH:/usr/openwin/bin
```

That's (for historic reasons) where X11 applications reside on Solaris. There you may find *xterm*, *xclock* and many other base clients for X11.

Comment: That's where they reside on releases up through (and including) Solaris 10.   On Solaris 11 they're now in `/usr/bin`, though compatibility symlinks remain for `/usr/openwin` & `/usr/X11` paths.

Answer (score 1):

I just use `xclock`. It's available on Solaris, but in a weird place; you can find it with:

```
find / -name xclock 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: On Solaris 10 and older, it's in `/usr/openwin/bin` - on Solaris 11 it's in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Solaris, but for any Linux users who encounter this question, you can use the `glxgears` application from the `mesa-utils` package.

Comment: Is there a `mesa-utils` package on *Solaris*?

Answer (score -1):

personally I copy a basic Graphic application in Java, like this one http://beginwithjava.blogspot.ch/2008/07/very-basic-java-graphics-3-examples.html (BasicFrame.java) , compile it and run it... of course you should have a JDK installed...